# I need to understand this syntax

Tags: php

What does this phrase do in php I am doing some OOP and came across it here in a tutorial.

```
<?php
//DB.class.php

class DB {

    protected $db_name = 'yourdatabasename';
    protected $db_user = 'databaseusername';
    protected $db_pass = 'databasepassword';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';
```

Comment: Do you know how classes work yet?

Comment: Start reading the manual or a book.

Comment: Which aspect? The `class` part or the `protected` part or the `variables` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protected is an access modifier it says that: 'only members of this class or any subclass may access this variable'
a PhP visibility tutorial for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Sorry guyz I did not complete that question but I got it figured out thanks

Comment: if my answer was helpfull could you upvote it, if it was correct accept it please :)

Comment: Babbleshack thanks for taking time to answer the question your statement is correct thanks